# Notation of the partial derivative of a composed function

Tags: derivatives, notation

Consider a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with generic notation $f(x,y)$, and the function $h:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(t)=f(x,t y)$ for some fixed $(x,y)$.

The function $h$ is itself differentiable. I have been fighting with colleagues over whether its derivative should be written
$$h'(t)=y \dfrac{\partial f(x, t y)}{\partial y}$$
or 
$$h'(t)=y \dfrac{\partial f(x, t y)}{\partial (ty)}.$$

We have the same object in mind---the derivative of $f$ with respect to its second variable, evaluated at $(x,ty)$---but we disagree on which of these is the right notational convention. Which of these above is correct, or at least more standard?

Answer (score 1):

It depends somewhat on the context, but I probably wouldn’t use either one.

You’re trying to express the idea that you’re taking the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its second argument. There are notations that express this more directly than the Leibniz notation: $f_2$, $f^{(2)}$, $D_2f$ and $\partial_2f$ are common ones that come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use the chain rule for $h(t)=f(x,ty)$ under the election of
$g(t)=(x,ty)^{\top}$ giving
$h'(t)=f'(g(t))\cdot g'(t)$. 
That is 
$$h'(t)=\frac{\partial f(x,ty)}{\partial y}y.$$

**Addendo**

I think it would be better to consider 
$G:\mathbb R^3\cdot\!\!\dashrightarrow\mathbb R^2$ via
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\x\\y\end{array}\right)
\longmapsto
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\ty\end{array}\right),
$$
and $f:\mathbb R^2\cdot\!\!\dashrightarrow\mathbb R^1$ as
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}v\\w\end{array}\right)\longmapsto f(v,w),
$$
then
$f(x,ty)=f\circ G(t,x,y)$.

So the chain rule would give that
$$\left[\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial t},\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial x},
\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial y}\right]$$ 
is equal the product of derivative
$$\left[\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial v},\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial w}\right]
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\\\y&0&t\end{array}\right)
=
\left[y\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial w},\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial v},t
\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial w}
\right]
.$$
That is
$$
\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial t}=y\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial w}
\quad,\quad \frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial v}
\quad,\quad \frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial y}=t\frac{\partial f(G)}{\partial w}.$$

Comment: Thanks, but I know the chain rule and was asking about the notational convention for $f'(g(t))$ (in your notation).

Comment: remember that $f'=\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]$ so $$f'(g)=\left[\frac{\partial f(x,ty)}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f(x,ty)}{\partial y}\right]$$